# Tool to manage and set right domain resolution

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

This horror story began a week ago when after an update, my Arcolinux install started behaving erratically and some sites (at random) won't open (they would after I left them for a while and tried again. I guessed it to be a DNS issue and looked it up. It seemed that using `dnsmasq` instead of `systemd-resolved` helped some people. So, I followed the Archwiki to the letter but now no sites will load. I then did different permutations and combinations of starting, stopping, and restarting `systemd-resolved`, `dnsmasq` and `NetworkManager`, which sometimes seemed to help (around 40% of the time and, as I told you, at random). Then yesterday, I couldn't not get any of the sites load, so I reinstalled the system.

It should have solved the problem but again I encountered the same problems (some sites would not load). Also, I noticed that in the freshly installed system, `systemd-resolved` was not running by default. I then again tried different permutations and combinations of starting, stopping, and restarting `systemd-resolved`, `dnsmasq` and `NetworkManager`. And again, problem not solved. (In fact, I had to wait for 15 minutes before Unix StackExchange would open).

Their (Arco's) forums seem to be very stagnant and I got no help there. Probably there is a program that manages DNS etc for us?

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.43.1
nameserver 2402:8100:3844::9
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
# Host addresses
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  adelie
::1        localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
```

Edit: I tried connecting other devices to the phone I use as a portable hotspot, and they didn't have the problem.

Edit2: `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.
# we changed nsswitch.conf to have access to nas servers
# This config file comes from the package filesystem
# Added two & otherwise installation script 140
# from ArcoLinuxD will change it

# This is the original line (minus 2 &)
# hosts: files & mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] & dns

# This is our ArcoLinux line
# hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] mdns dns wins myhostname

passwd: files mymachines systemd
group: files mymachines systemd
shadow: files

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] mdns dns wins myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

Comment: If the problem persisted afer reinstalling, are you sure it's actually a problem with your OS? Do you have any other devices on the same network? Do they work as expected? Could the problem be with the DNS server you have set in your router?

Comment: @terdon I use my phone as a hotspot and yeah my phone works fine.

Comment: And what if you connect another device to your phone in the same way, does that also work fine?

Comment: @terdon Yeah it does. Also, I tried connecting to another phone and got the same result on my pc.

Comment: Well, dang then. Could you please [edit] your question and add this information? Especially the fact that you connected another device to the same phone and that did not have the problem.

Comment: The contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` might be interesting, too

Comment: @Panki Updated the question